# iphone app keywords localisation

Tags: iphone, localization, keyword

Wondering if anyone can help me understand how the localisation works with keywords. I have an app in English. I would like to make search easier for users in non english speaking countries by including keywords in german, french, spanish etc..However I would like to keep my app the same i.e. in english.

Is this possible? will app store accept this? i.e. submitting just keywords for localisation.

Many thanks in advance for help..
pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news.  You can localize the keywords in iTunes Connect by selecting "Manage Localizations" which should take you to the screen below.  You'll see the keywords are available for edit and localization.  This will require you to fill in the description and keywords with the new language so you could fill the description with English and only localize the keywords.  I think this addresses your question.

[image]

I think you may have to do this during an application update or initial application submission because I cannot currently add a new language for localization (my application is live).

Comment: According to Apple's docs, you can only ADD a NEW localized app description & keywords when your app is in an Editable state. So basically when you release your next version you can do it. However, you can EDIT an existing localized description whenever you want. There is a complete tutorial on this here: http://www.ibabbleon.com/add-localized-app-store-description-tutorial.html